# OAuth2 request with React Native

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, react-native

I am using the Yelp API for my mobile application. The Yelp API requires an OAuth2 request (consumer key, secret key, token, secret token). How do I make the request with react native?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still finding themselves looking for this answer, in ios/android:
[react-native-app-auth](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth). Hopefully they'll add react native windows support at some point.

Answer (score -1):

You can make network request using fetch api,
refer  http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.26/docs/tutorial.html#fetching-real-data

refer https://github.com/github/fetch for documentation

```
  fetch(apiUrl, options)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json()
  }).then(function(json) {
    console.log('parsed json', json)
  }).catch(function(ex) {
    console.log('parsing failed', ex)
  })
```

Comment: this is just a simple fetch request, where is the oauth part?